# Creating a Table of Squared Differences through a Single Function

Tags: difference-equations, table, subset

I am having trouble creating a table of squared differences within a single function. I can manually create this table through creating six different `alphaDiff` functions in the following code:

```
ClearAll;

(* Create an ellipse at the origin. *)
a1 = 10;
a2 = 20;
b = 0;
ellipse[s_] := {a1 Cos[s], a2  Sin[s], b};

(* Create some points. *)
ptLocs = {{3.5, -0.7, -1.4}, {-1.0, 3.6, 0.7}, {2.7, -7.6, -0.7}, {-1.4, 2.9, 1.5}};

(* Create alpha by taking the dot product. *)
alpha[i_, s_] := Dot[ptLocs[[i]], sensorUnitized[s]];

(* Compute the matrix of squared differences and plot it. *)
alphaDiff1[s_] := (alpha[1, s] - alpha[2, s])^2;
alphaDiff2[s_] := (alpha[1, s] - alpha[3, s])^2;
alphaDiff3[s_] := (alpha[1, s] - alpha[4, s])^2;
alphaDiff4[s_] := (alpha[2, s] - alpha[3, s])^2;
alphaDiff5[s_] := (alpha[2, s] - alpha[4, s])^2;
alphaDiff6[s_] := (alpha[3, s] - alpha[4, s])^2;
alphaDiffAll[s_] := {rangeDiff1[s], rangeDiff2[s], rangeDiff3[s], 
   rangeDiff4[s], rangeDiff5[s], rangeDiff6[s]};
alphaDiffTable = Table[rangeDiffAll[s], {s, 1, 50, 0.1}];
alphaDiffPlot = ListPlot[Transpose[alphaDiffTable], 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Alpha Difference Table", Bold, 18]]
```

The code above produces the following plot:

[image]

However, I would like to implement the same functionality by writing

```
alphaDiff1[s_] := (alpha[1, s] - alpha[2, s])^2;
alphaDiff2[s_] := (alpha[1, s] - alpha[3, s])^2;
alphaDiff3[s_] := (alpha[1, s] - alpha[4, s])^2;
alphaDiff4[s_] := (alpha[2, s] - alpha[3, s])^2;
alphaDiff5[s_] := (alpha[2, s] - alpha[4, s])^2;
alphaDiff6[s_] := (alpha[3, s] - alpha[4, s])^2;
```

as a single function. My initial attempt was to notice that

```
validSets = Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2}]

{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}

MatrixForm[validSets];
Dimensions[validSets];
```

returned the correct subsets. However, when I combine this with the `Table` function

```
validSets = Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2}];
alphaAll[i_, j_, s_] := (alpha[i, s] - alpha[j, s])^2;
alphaAllTable = Table[alphaAll[i, j, s], {i, 
    List[validSets[[All, 1]]]}, {j, {validSets[[All, 2]]}}, {s, 1, 50,0.1}];
squaredRangeDifferencePlot2 = ListPlot[alphaAllTable, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Alpha Difference Table 2", Bold, 18]]
```

the following plot is returned

[image]

I believe the problem is with the line

```
alphaAllTable = Table[alphaAll[i, j, s], {i, 
    List[validSets[[All, 1]]]}, {j, {validSets[[All, 2]]}}, {s, 1, 50,0.1}];
```

as `validSets[[All, 1]]` isn't a `List`, so `Table` does not interpret `{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3}` as a `List`. Is there an alternative way to implement this functionality in Mathematica?

Comment: Your code does not execute because you have not provided all of the required definitions. To calculate the squared differences: `(Subtract @@@
    Map[alpha[#, s] &, Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2}], {2}])^2`

Comment: Thanks. I can therefore write `test=Table[Subtract @@@ Map[sensorsAll[#, s] &, Subsets[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {2}], {2}], {s, 1, 50, 0.1}];`. It appears that it isn't necessary to make a function of three variables.